# Confusion with `Array#[]` output in IRB

Tags: ruby, arrays, slice

I was playing with [`Array#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) in my `IRB` to learn it. All my tries are below:

Below code is understood.

```
[2,3][0..1]
#=> [2, 3]
```

*Why does the below code giving `empty array`?*

```
[2,3][-1,0]
#=> []
```

*But why does the code giving `nil` value?*

```
[2,3][0,-1]
#=> nil
```

Comment: you're making a new array and then immediately slicing it

Comment: @AJcodez my confusion with the `nil` output. Couldn't understand the working.

Comment: return value of `[2,3][2]`, `[2,3][2,1]`, `[2,3][3]` and `[2,3][3,1]` are more confusing. Have to remember some corner case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[2,3][1,2]` will start at the index 1 and select the next 2 values.

`[2,3][-1,0]` will start at the index -1 and select the next 0 values. -1 starts from the end of the array and works backwards.

**EDIT:**

To answer the updated question, `[2,3][0,-1]` would start at the index 0 but since you can't have a negative number for the length, it will return `nil`.

If you wanted to select the value before the index, just decrease the index by 1 and have the length as 1.

**EDIT2:**

Ruby wasn't designed to accept a negative length value but was designed to accept a negative starting value.

Also, in the docs "Additionally, an empty array is returned when the starting index for an element range is at the end of the array." - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D

After drilling down through the Ruby source code, the `rb_ary_subseq` function will return `nil` if either the starting index or length values are less than zero.

But before the `rb_ary_subseq` is called, the `rb_ary_aref` function changes the negative starting index value to a positive with `start += array.length` to give the same effect.

There is no code to make the negative length conversion.

So `[2,3][-1,0]` will return an empty array because the length isn't less than zero and because of the description in the docs referenced.

`[2,3][0,-1]` will return `nil` because the length is less than zero.

Source code links:

`rb_ary_aref` - http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/array.c#1042

`rb_ary_subseq` - http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/array.c#989

Comment: Okay, how does `0` length and `-1` length array differs,conceptually both should be either `empty array`? But why not so?

Comment: `rb_ary_subseq` function will return `nil` if either the starting index less than `0`. if so then why `[2,3][-1,0]` does give `[]` but not `nil`?

Comment: `[2,3][-1,0]` gets changed to `[2,3][1,0]` by `rb_ary_aref` on line 1051 to make both positive. See paragraph 4 from my second edit.

Comment: perfect explanation,Gr8 :) happy to get help from you!